# Ip Configuration in Fortigate 60d

Tags: firewall, fortigate, fortinet

I have a fortigate 60d which bought around 3-4 years ago. Today i tried to install over of fiber internet. I connected my forti with 192.168.3.1 then i clicked wizard and entered new values and new ip range (192.168.0.50 - 192.168.0.210). Also i set ip of machine 192.168.0.1. But now when i am trying to enter 0.1 or 3.1 i couldn't login the forti.

When i looked to my ip configuration it is giving a different ip as 169.254.96.217 . I pressed around 15 seconds to the reset button backside of the forti but nothing changed.

How can i connect the machine again or how can i reset my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i modified fortigate it will disable dhcp. I made static ip as 192.168.3.20 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0 then i can enter the system.